# Variable importance values: how to normalize

Tags: variables, normalization

I want to identify a set of variables that can predict post-stroke pain (outcome).
I have >20 covariates.
I fitted 3 ML models: elastic net, random forests, and gradient boosting. From each model, I have obtained variable importance values. However, **I want to normalize the importance values (%) for each ML method or find the relative importance of each variable (%) for the outcome.**

Here is the example of the code I have but can not get the result I anticipate:
set.seed(20231116)

## Train the Elastic Net model with cross-validation

elastic_net_cv_model <- cv.glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha = 0.5, lambda = seq(0.01, 1, length = 100))

## Find the optimal lambda value based on cross-validation results

best_lambda_elastic_net <- elastic_net_cv_model$lambda.min

## Train the Elastic Net model with the optimal lambda value

elastic_net_model <- glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha = 0.5, lambda = best_lambda_elastic_net)

## Get coefficients from the Elastic Net model

coefficients <- coef(elastic_net_model)

## Extract the coefficients for each feature

feature_coefficients <- as.matrix(coefficients)[-1, ]

## Normalize the coefficients to have a sum of absolute values equal to 1

normalized_importance <- feature_coefficients / sum(abs(feature_coefficients))

## Print or use the normalized importance values

print(normalized_importance)

Please see some results to understand why i need to obtain normalized importance values (%)

The elastic net looks like this:
Age 0.00000
Sex -0.12460
Country of birth -0.1283
...
...

The Random forests:
Age 34.08
Sex 13.11
Country of birth 11:00
...
...